# SAS Data organization

Tags: statistics, sas, stata, analysis

[Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBJiv.png)

I have data set like the attached picture where I want only the observations that have same numsecur every year.

How do I do this in SAS proc sql function? Will this be easier to do in STATA? If so what procedure can I use?

Comment: Sorry - I don't see a picture...  Could you not use a code block, instead?

Comment: so for your example you just want 1998 and 1999?

Comment: Yes in this example I want the observations with ID 001598 for year 1996,1998,1999

Comment: If you click on the title you will see the table

Comment: What if one ID has the same `numsecur` in some years but not others? Which do you want to keep?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you want your final dataset look like? It's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you would like to keep the observations from the same company/individual only if the company has the same numsecur every year. So, here is what I would try using STATA:

```
input ID YEAR EXEC SUM
    1573 1997 50 1080 //
    1581 1997 51  300 //
    1598 1996 54   80 //
    1598 1998 54   80 //
    1598 1999 54   80 //
    1602 1996 55  112.6 //
    1602 1997 55  335.965 //
    1575 1997 50 1080 //
    1575 1998 51 1080 //
    1595 1996 54   80 //
    1595 1998 54   30 //
    1595 1999 54   80 //
    1605 1996 55  112.6 //
    1605 1997 55  335.965 //
end

bysort ID SUM: gen drop=cond(_N==1, 0,_n)
drop if drop==0
```

The results show ( based on my data):

```
   
    ID      YEAR   EXEC  SUM    drop    

1.  1575    1997    50  1080    1   
2.  1575    1998    51  1080    2   
3.  1595    1999    54  80      1   
4.  1595    1996    54  80      2   
5.  1598    1996    54  80      1   

6.  1598    1998    54  80      2   
7.  1598    1999    54  80      3
```

Comment: I am happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You look like a new user to stackoverflow.  Welcome.  Your question is getting down voted for at least three reasons:

```
1) It's not really clear what you want from your description of the problem and the data
   you're providing

2) You haven't shown any attempts at what you've tried

3) Providing your data as a picture is not great.  It's most helpful if you're going
   to provide data to provide it so it's easy for others to consume in their program.  
   After all, you're asking for our help make it easier for us to help you.  If You 
   included something like the following we just have to copy and paste to create your
   dataset to work with:

    DATA test;    
    INPUT ID YEAR EXEC SUM;
       DATALINES;
    1573 1997 50 1080
    1581 1997 51  300
    1598 1996 54   80
    1598 1998 54   80
    1598 1999 54   80
    1602 1996 55  112.6
    1602 1997 55  335.965
       ;
    RUN;
```

That being said the following MAY give you what you're looking for but it's only a guess as I'm not sure if this is really what you're asking:

```
proc sql no print;
     create table testout as
            select *,count(*) as cnt
      from test
            group by sum
                  having cnt > 1;
quit;
```

Are you asking: show all rows where the same SUM is used or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have been more clear in my question. I actually wanted what you said. As for my attempt I created a lag variable and then a difference variable between the lag and numsecur; then I removed the observations that were other than zero.

Comment: If my answer works for you click on the check mark to accept the answer and click on the up triangle.